# importing netbeans android project into android studio

Tags: android, netbeans, android-studio

I used to work on a project on netbeans which turn out to be the least intuitive IDE for android, now trying to switch to android-studio I can't manage to find way neither to export properly the netbeans project nor importing the netbeans project into android-studio ..

How can I import netbeans android project into android studio? it has something to do with gradle I suppose ..

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe late, but i think can help someone else.
   Android Studio can import netbeans android projects. Just open import project window by selecting **File -> new -> Import Project** and address the netbeans project root. Android Studio does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I partly ran into the same and solved it so far.
You can add .jar files under app/libs paste it there and right click it -> add library. (I believe)

It should look like this. [Android .jar into Libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSusU.png)

This would be partly a solution, you have to create an android xml as well.

Comment: Your answer is considering to import a library. In fact, the question concerns an existing project that shall stay the same but used in a new IDE. If your answer takes care of that, please extend your answer with further steps and explanations